# Apache configuration fine tuning

Tags: apache

I run a very simple website (basically a redirect based on a php database) which gets on average 5 visits per second throughout the day, but at peak times (usually 2-3 times a day), this may go up to even 300 visits/s or more. I've modified the default apache settings as follows (based on various info found online as I'm not an expert):

```
Start Servers: 5 (default) / 25 (now)
Minimum Spare Servers: 5 (default) / 50 (now)
Maximum Spare Servers: 10 (default) / 100 (now)
Server Limit: 256 (default) / 512 (now)
Max Clients: 150 (default) / 450 (now)
Max Requests Per Child: 10000 (default)
Keep-Alive: On (default) / Off (now)
Timeout: 300 (default)
```

Server (VPS) specs:

```
4x 3199.998 MHz, 512 KB Cache, QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6) 
8GB RAM (Memory: 8042676k/8912896k available (5223k kernel code, 524700k absent, 345520k reserved, 7119k data, 1264k init)
70GB SSD disk
CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 kvm – server
```

During average loads the server handles just fine. Problems occur almost every day during peak traffic times, as in http time-outs or extremely long response/load times.
Question is, do I need to get a better server or can I improve response times during peak traffic by further tuning Apache config? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need to enable mod_cache with mod_mem_cache, another parameter that i always configure is ulimits:

- nofile to get more sockets
- nproc to get more processes

http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2012/12/setting-apache2-ulimit-for-maximum-prefork-performance/

finally TCP Tuning and Network, check all net.core and net.ipv4 parameters to get less latency

http://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/linux/

Comment: Thank you. Will try to fiddle with those too.